# select all checkboxes in jquery not triggered properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to set values of selected checkbox to text input

For example: see this image [Click](http://postimg.org/image/y5vqu3bct/)

Problem is when i click "Select All" checkbox "child" checkboxes are checked but value not set in textbox and values set when i uncheck the "Select All" checkbox

I want to get checkbox values in array so i am using map function,

Please see jquery on fiddle

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/y2zbvo06/)

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="" id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
    <label for="selectAll">Select All</label><br>

    <div class="child">
        <input type="checkbox" class="selectCb" value="1" id="one">
        <label for="one">One</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="two" class="selectCb" value="2">
        <label for="two">Two</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="selectCb" value="3" id="three">
        <label for="three">Three</label><br>
    </div>


    <input type="text" id="textBox">
</form>
```

**EDIT**

**Both codes are working**

```
$(document).on("click", "#selectAll", function () {

    var chkAll = $(".child input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() { 
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    $("#textBox").val(chkAll.join(' '));

});
```

Check on fiddle [fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/LzLdqzab/)

```
    $(document).on("change", "#selectAll", function () {

    var chkAll = $(".child input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked).map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    $("#textBox").val(chkAll.join(' '));
});
```

check on fiddle [fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/ohLwuf1x/)

Now my doubt is which one is better and correct ?

because i want to set background image for all checkbox, so I hide all checkboxes using css

```
 #form input[type="checkbox"] {
       display: none;
    }
```

And set background image for checkbox using following css code

Set Background for "Select All" Checkbox

```
input[type="checkbox"]#selectAll + label#selectAllLbl::before {
    content: '';
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/uhql9zd5p/chk_uncheck.png') no-repeat;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]#selectAll:checked + label#selectAllLbl::before {
    content: '';
    background: url('http://s9.postimg.org/6k81psojf/chk_enabled.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Set Background for "child" Check boxes

```
input[type="checkbox"].selectCb + label.childLbl::before {
    content: '';
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/uhql9zd5p/chk_uncheck.png') no-repeat;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"].selectCb:checked + label.childLbl::before {
    content: '';
    background: url('http://s9.postimg.org/6k81psojf/chk_enabled.png') no-repeat;
}
```

so is it right ? to use hidden checkbox id and class in jquery

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">

<input type="checkbox" class="selectCb" value="1" id="one">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch `change` to `click` in the second argument:

```
$(document).on("change", ".selectCb", function () {

    var values = $(".child input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() { 
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    $("#textBox").val(values.join(' '));
});



$(document).on("click", "#selectAll", function () {

    var chkAll = $(".child input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() { 
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    $("#textBox").val(chkAll.join(' '));


});
```

Comment: i was updated my question, please check and thanks for your answer

Comment: The example in fiddle 3 seems to work well for me. I don't see any reason why this wouldn't be a reasonable option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `selectAll` to toggle the checks on other checkboxes use `prop()` to do it. Using `this.checked` will indicate whether to check or uncheck them

```
$(document).on("change", "#selectAll", function () {

    var chkAll = $(".child input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked).map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    $("#textBox").val(chkAll.join(' '));

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y2zbvo06/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: i was updated my question, please check and thanks for your answer

Comment: You completely changed the question. Now the answers don't match. You should have started a new question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding checkbox you can assign negative margin to it.

Please refer below CSS snippet :

```
#form {overflow:hidden}

#form input[type="checkbox"]{
margin-left:-25px
}
```

Also want to repeat what jonmrich has already said to switch "change to click" in the second argument for "#selectAll" checkbox.

Thanks